# Uncaught ReferenceError: watermark is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

Hi am new in javascript , when am trying to add watermark in our page then getting an error like watermark is not defined please tell me where am wrong , what should i do to solve this error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WaterMArk</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Watermark</h1>
    <hr />

    <script>
        watermark(['img/f.jpg', 'img/grator1.png'])
            .image(watermark.image.center(0.5))
            .then(function (img) {
                document.getElementById('center').appendChild(img);
            });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well what is "watermark"? Whatever it is, your not loading it, so it's undefined

Answer (score 1):

Well it's very clear browser doesn't recognize the keyword watermark

you may need to include watermark js to your head tag

you can find the same here

https://github.com/brianium/watermarkjs/blob/master/dist/watermark.js